# jquery Owl Carousel: how to make current slide focused

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, slider, carousel

I am using Owl Image carousel.  http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html

it is working fine.  i want to make current slide Little bit Bigger in size than other slide.
in other words i want to make current slide's width bigger.

to make current slide Bigger i have added following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000,
        responsive: true,
        addClassActive: true,
        items: 4,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3],
    });
});
```

here i have added Active class to Active slides. i tried to zoom Current Slide.

for that i have added following style sheet code.

```
.active: nth - child(2) {
    transform: scale(1.2);

}
```

But when carousel Scroll second Item Doesn't stay Highlighted.  need help to Zoom the Current slide in Owl Carousel.

**is there any other Responsive Carousel that Zoom the Current Slider?** [image]

Comment: You are showing 4 slides at a time so how can you detect middle one?
also hint:- you need to change width and height of that image

Comment: how can i change the hieght of that image. as carousel will scroll the Current slide item will change. so current slide item should be zoom With Transform:scale(2.2)

Comment: did you figure this out?  I'm having the same challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gjgmqznq/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

        autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
        responsive: true,
        addClassActive: true,
        items: 4,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3],
        stopOnHover:true,
        afterMove:function(){
            //reset transform for all item
            $(".owl-item").css({
                transform:"none"
            })
            //add transform for 2nd active slide
            $(".active").eq(1).css({
                transform:"scale(1.9)",
                zIndex:3000,

            })

        },
        //set init transform
        afterInit:function(){
            $(".active").eq(1).css({
                transform:"scale(1.9)",
                zIndex:3000,

            })
        }

    });

})
```